# How to generate passwords using PassGAN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

Sorry if this question is very basic and simple, I'm a beginner at programming and especially machine learning.

I'm trying to evaluate the performance of the PassGAN AI by having it generate passwords, and then I compare them to a testing list that contains around a million passwords and see how many matches I get.

I have managed to train the algorithm, but I'm not sure how to get it to generate a password file with generated passwords.

Link to the GitHub source of PassGAN: https://github.com/d4ichi/PassGAN

Training & Testing file: https://github.com/d4ichi/PassGAN/releases/download/data/rockyou-test.txt

*Note: I did have to modify some of the code, and downgrade the TensorFlow version to get it to work.

I simply replaced all:

`import tensorflow as tf`

with

`import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf`

`tf.disable_v2_behavior()`

in every .py file.

I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You actually should be good to go from here - I was able to generate password samples after making the changes you mentioned. Just execute sample.py script.

On the other hand, it's worth mentioning that Tensorflow differs significantly between versions 1 and 2. If you only need to generate passwords then this will suffice, but if you would like to learn programming or machine learning, this project is probably not the right direction.

There are PassGAN implementations based on Tensorflow 2, for example:
https://github.com/Riathoir/PASSGAN-IWGAN-Tensorflow-2

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I hadn't realized I could just set a different input directory for the sample.py file.